# Vuforia Text Recognition in android

Tags: android, vuforia

I am playing with android vuforia text recognition sample application provided by Vuforia and I am able to run the app. I am seeing the rectangle being drawn around the word in it. I want to get the word when I tap/click on the rectangle.

On single tap I have written below code:

```
float X = event.getRawX(); 
//get screen touch point 
float Y = event.getRawY(); 
// get screen touch point 
if(wordDescList != null && wordDescList.size()>0) 
{ 
    // wordDescList is a list of (WordDesc object with word,Ax,Ay,Bx,By respectively)
    for (WordDesc wordDesc : wordDescList)
    { 
        if(X > wordDesc.Ax && X < wordDesc.Ay && Y > wordDesc.Bx && Y < wordDesc.By) 
        {
            // touched word 
        } 
    }
 }
```

Sorry for typos.

Comment: anything tried so far ? Do you have any code you could show to us ?

Comment: On single tap I have written below code::::
                float X = event.getRawX(); // get screen touch point
                float Y = event.getRawY(); // get screen touch point
                if(wordDescList != null && wordDescList.size()>0) // wordDescList is a list of (WordDesc object with word,Ax,Ay,Bx,By respectively){ for (WordDesc wordDesc : wordDescList){
if(X > wordDesc.Ax && X < wordDesc.Ay && Y > wordDesc.Bx && Y < wordDesc.By)
                    {// touched word }
}
}

Comment: You did not really say what the actual problem is - do you get inside the last if but you just don't know how to get the word? Something else?

Comment: The actual problem is, when I tap on word/Rectangle, I am not able to get it.

Comment: OK, but you need to isolate it a little more. If you answer my questions I might be able to help you...